# Bluetooth earpiece spontaneously disconnects and reconnects while talking

Tags: bluetooth

I have an Xperia Z3 Compact phone and a Plantronics Voyager Edge bluetooth earpiece. Recently the earpiece sometimes (usually once or twice a day) spontaneously disconnects from the phone and immediately reconnects (which causes the audio to halt for a couple of seconds). It might also be happening not only when I'm talking, I can't tell.

The problem is I don't know if the problem is with the phone or with the earpiece.

I upgraded the earpiece to the latest firmware but it didn't help.

I don't have any other bluetooth devices to check the phone with or another phone to check the earpiece with.

Is there any way I can check it?