# Bluetooth headphones occasionally disconnect and immediately reconnect

Tags: bluetooth-audio

I use a Huawei MediaPad X2 (GEM-701L with Android 4.3) and a couple of different Bluetooth headphones (the latest are Sony WF-1000XM3). I listen to music through the headphones and they occasionally disconnect and reconnect (maybe once every 15 minutes on average, but I cannot detect any regularity). Sometimes they go silent for a few seconds, then they say "BT disconnected", then immediately "BT connected", and the music is back; the whole episode takes maybe 10-15 seconds. Sometimes they disconnect while playing and immediately reconnect with a pause in the music of perhaps only 2-3 seconds. I read whatever I could find on the web about power settings, etc. but I believe this has nothing to do with that--again, it is completely irregular, not after a specific time. Somehow the problem must be on the Android side, for it manifests very similarly with both sets of headphones. I believe it is not a wireless signal issue, for it happens in very different settings, including sitting at the desk with less than a meter between the devices involved.

I know nothing to Bluetooth, but I tried to capture Bluetoot HCI packets in btsnoop_hci.log, waited for one such event, and I inspected the log with Wireshark. Here is, I believe, the relevant part of the log:

[image: Relevant part of the log in Wireshark]

I believe the event in questionstarts at 1104.784603 and ends at 1104.895574, for the rest before and after looks a perfectly regular transmission. It is odd, though, because the event looks a tad too short and I do not see any sign of connection reestablished at the end of the event.

Anyway, alas, I understand nothing of the protocol. Does anyone have an idea of what might be going on or how to investigate further?

p.s.: I could not find problem descriptions on the web truly matching the problem I have. Except perhaps this one, fairly old and never answered: [Bluetooth earpiece spontaneously disconnects and reconnects while talking](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/132351).

Comment: I get this happening also. I get it alot between the car and the house, and house to yard. I'm attributing this to my WiFi attempts of the phone to re/dis-connect to its known node. Since I also leave on Bluetooth scanning, I believe even in a closely passing vehicle, some handshaking occurs enough to cause disruption. It's the world we live in, and I've come to accept it as a minor distraction at worst.

Comment: I am not sure what is the potential connection to WiFi, but (looking to the Bluetooth log) it does not seem to me that there is any evidence of any handshaking with any other device (and it would be surprising when I am simply sitting at home).

Comment: Nothing on a device happens "simultaneously". Every action is an interruption to all other actions. Small, unobtrusive interruptions make the device feel to the user like a lot of things happen simultaneously; all should cooperate to make a seamless experience. Depending on privilege and scope, that interruption can be small and unfelt or longer and noticeable to the user. In my case, communication interruptions are the most felt, especially background communications interrupting foreground ones.